# Problem with authorisation when call firebase functions from web page

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-401

I faced a problem with my rest server that's deployed on firebase functions. When I make a GET request from postman it works fine and it gives me no problem at all. BUT when I call my endpoints from the webpage I receive error 401 in the console.
Here's the code for the login.

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = {
            id: req.body.id,
            password: req.body.password
        }

        const auth = getAuth();

        const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user);

        if (!valid) throw ({ code: "validation-failed", message: errors, status: 400 });

        let data = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, user.id, user.password);
        let token = await data.user.getIdToken();

        console.log("TOKEN: " + token);

        res.cookie('_token', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: 3600000 });

        return res.status(202).json({ message: "OK" });
    } catch (err) {
        switch (err.code) {
            case "validation-failed":
                return res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message });

            case "auth/user-not-found":
            case "auth/wrong-password":
                return res.status(401).json({ message: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });

            default:
                return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })

        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this middleware here to check if who's calling is authenticated

```
const FBAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies._token || '';


    if (token == '') {
        console.error("No token found");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Not authorized" });
    }

    try {
        let decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
        req.user = decodedToken;
        console.log("USER ID: ", req.user.uid)

        let data = await db.collection(`users`).where("userId", '==', req.user.uid).limit(1).get();

        req.user.username = data.docs[0].data().username;
        req.user.uid = data.docs[0].data().userId;
        req.user.email = data.docs[0].data().email;
        req.user.imageUrl = data.docs[0].data().imageUrl;

        return next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(403).json("Error while verifying token: ", err);
    }
}
```

Of course the middleware is not present in the login endpoint so it doesn't give me any error (so the server actually works) BUT when I try to call this endpoint here:

```
const getAuthenticatedUser = (req, res) => {
    let userData = {};
    let notifications = [];

    db.collection(`users`).doc(`${req.user.username}`).get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                userData = doc.data();
                userData.emailVerified = req.user.email_verified;
            }
            return db
                .collection(`rewardNotifications`)
                .where("username", "==", req.user.username)
                .orderBy("createAt", "desc")
                .get()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                notifications.push({
                    notificationId: doc.id,
                    createAt: doc.data().createAt,
                    message: doc.data().message,
                    position: doc.data().position,
                    read: doc.data().read,
                    type: doc.data().type
                })
            });
            return res.json({
                userData: userData,
                notifications: notifications
            });
        })
}
```

I receive 401 BUT only if I call the endpoint from my frontend, it doesn't give me this error in Postman.
Do you have any idea about what's causing this? If so, please help me understand.

Comment: You're using the Firebase Auth client SDK on a backend?  That's not a supported situation.  You're going to run into problems with that.  The client SDK is only meant to be used in the browser.  You're supposed to auth the user in your app, then pass a token to your backend as shown in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: Also I'll point out that you're not doing anything in getAuthenticatedUser to check for and log errors, so you're missing out on more detailed information.  You should track this down to a specific line of code that fails, along with the error message it generates.  In addition, your question needs to be clear about the specific result that you expect this code to give, and provide enough information on how to reproduce the unexpected result.

Comment: Thank you, I was using firebase admin in a bad way. Now I reworked the entire auth system and now it works like a charm. Many thanks Doug